# Cannot read or set properties inside function that is being passed as a parameter

Tags: angular, typescript

```
deleteDialog(item, func: Function) {
    this.dialogService
      .open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
        context: {
          title:"Are you sure?",
          cancelClss: "info",
          confirmClss: "danger",
        },
      })
      .onClose.subscribe((confirmed) => {
        if (confirmed) func(item);
      });
  }
```

All this function does is that it opens a dialog and returns the result, I want to pass the function that I want to execute if confirmed dynamically to be able to reuse the dialog elsewhere. 
For example I have this function

```
deleteCurrencyImplementation(cur: Currency) {
 this.showSpinner = true; 
 ...
 }
```

the function gets executed and the object is being passed correctly but if I try to read / set anything inside for example show spinner, which is a `public` property and set to `true` Angular throws `TypeError` because of `undefined`. 
  This is how I pass the function inside html.

```
 <show-datasource 
[tableConfig]="config" [data]="currenciesFromApi"
(deleteEmitter)="deleteDialog($event,deleteCurrencyImplementation)"> 
 </show-datasource>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What exaclty are you trying to read/set within `deleteCurrencyImplementation`?

Comment: I will add a basic example and edit my question @lbsn

Comment: Hi Ari, can you please show a snippet of the ```html``` you are binding to...we're trying to figure out why the ```$event``` is undefined

Comment: Can you make http://stackblitz.com/ sample?  runnable code would be very helpful

Comment: $event is not undefined and is correctly being passed as I stated above the problem is when I try to access other private and public variables. I will edit the question and the full snippet though. @AshwynHorton

Comment: @AriMuayad: Try `deleteDialog($event, deleteCurrencyImplementation.bind(this))`

Comment: You need to `bind` you function to `this`

Comment: Yes, now it is working bind was what I was missing. If either of you could make an answer with a bit of explanation I would be grateful .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) you callback function to `this`. This can be done in multiple ways.

Declare the function like this:

```
deleteCurrencyImplementation = (cur: Currency) => {
 this.showSpinner = true; 
 ...
 }
```

Bind before calling it:

```
    .onClose.subscribe((confirmed) => {
            if (confirmed) {
               const bounded = func.bind(this);
               bounded(item);
            }
          });
```